# Clarification regarding In App Rating iOS

Tags: ios, rating

As per the apple documentation, if we use `SKStoreReviewController` for in app Rating, then the popup can be shown for 3 times per app per year.
I have 2 doubts:

1. Is this policy per version of app or per app. If I have 3 versions of app in a year, then how will it work?
2. If the app is uninstalled and installed again, so it will count 3 times after second install or first?

Answer (score 0):

I can't find the information on `Apple's` doc/guide but in my opinion :

1 → per app

2 → you can test it by installing an app and making the rating view appear then uninstall and reinstall and check if the rating view is coming back

good luck